# Sharing objects owned via smart pointer

Tags: c++, oop, smart-pointers

Basically i have a one struct that contains objects to share between classes as following;

```
struct CoreComponents
{
    std::unique_ptr<a> m_A = std::make_unique<a>();
    std::unique_ptr<b> m_B;
    std::unique_ptr<c> m_C = std::make_unique<c>();
};
```

And in my main class i own it via *unique_ptr*;

```
class Game
{
    ...
  private:
    std::unique_ptr<CoreComponents> m_Components;
    ...
};
```

Then i have other **n** classes which i need to access that ***m_Components*** object from it's functions without creating copies. (i will not modify contents of that object)

I tried using *shared_ptr* to hold ***m_Components*** in ***Game*** class then pass it to other classes (to their constructors) via value and store it but that scenario causes memory leaks. (i use memcheck for checking leaks) I found out that it's the cause of the leak but i couldn't figure out why exactly.

**Shared_ptr scenario**

Constructor of class which i need to access CoreComponents object;

```
GameScene::GameScene(std::shared_ptr<CoreComponents> components)
: m_Components(std::move(components))
```

I'm trying to hold it as member of GameScene class then use it in functions;

```
std::shared_ptr<CoreComponents> m_Components;
```

And this is how i pass it from inside of the Game class;

```
auto gs = std::make_unique<GameScene>(m_Components)
```

General usage inside GameScene class;

```
m_Components->m_A->draw(*m_OtherObjectInsideGameScene);
```

So what is the best way to create similar design using modern c++?
I was trying to avoid Singleton pattern but do i have to use it to achieve this or it's possible with better smart pointer usage?

PS: CoreComponents struct needs to be deleted from memory when Game class is destroyed.

Comment: If you have problems with code not working, post that code - i.e. the code using shared pointers.

Comment: @NeilButterworth thanks for the feedback. added code about shared pointer scenario.

Comment: Remember, `std::weak_ptr` is a thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you correctly separate the concerns of *ownership* and *usage*.  The only trouble you have is how to forward the components to the rest of your system.

I would keep your owning structure, and create dedicated structures for the specific users:

```
struct CoreComponents {
   unique_ptr<A> a; unique_ptr<B> b; ...
};

struct PartOfTheSystem {
  void use(A& a, B& b);
};

struct Game {
  CoreComponents components;
  PartOfTheSystem user;

  void stuff() {
    user.use(*components.a, *components.b);
  }
};
```

Yes: more typing.

But also: very clear logic: construction/ownership and use are separate concerns, and this is perfectly clear by design!  Also refer to https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rr-smartptrparam.

Comment: The use of a reference makes this example good. However, didn't the OP say something about storage?

Comment: I understood not, and "... access that m_Components object from it's functions without creating copies"

Comment: My interpretation is that said functions would be getting to the object from a pointer stored as a member variable. Stored! Storing raw pointers => bad. Just passing them into one-off functions is borderline acceptable though.

Comment: Indeed, to express a long-term relation, a `weak_ptr` may serve a better job, in some situations.

But then again... you lose control over who does and who does not own your objects.  When you accept R.3 and R.4, you're safe: someone else takes care of the objects pointed to as long as you need them.  That intent is very clear and you can structure your program accordingly.  Storing raw pointers is not bad by itself.

Comment: @xtofl instead of taking as shared_ptr or unique_ptr i tried const reference and hold it as it is that's cleaned up all memory leaks.

Comment: You make my day.  Glad this design decision served your use case so well!

Answer (score 1):

The best way if you have shared objects is indeed to use a `shared_ptr`.

A `unique_ptr` is for unique ownership.

If you had memory leaks, it's time to investigate why that was, and fix them! Your report suggests a cyclical reference. Check for accidental lambda capture, and in some places you perhaps meant to use `weak_ptr` instead.

Using a singleton for this is like fixing your car's broken tyre by setting the whole thing on fire and taking a donkey instead. Your `unique_ptr` approach is more like fixing your car's broken tyre by removing it and driving on rims for the lols.

Comment: Not sure I agree here.  If I understand gotw91 correctly, the non-owning part of the world does not need to know about any owning pointers.  (https://herbsutter.com/2013/06/05/gotw-91-solution-smart-pointer-parameters/)

Comment: @xtofl A load of rubbish. If you don't need to share ownership pass a ref to the shared_ptr. You can then obtain a weak_ptr from it if you need to store a non-owning pointer to the resource. But stripping away all those ownership semantics is just silly.

Comment: @xtofl Always remember, everything you read (including what I say) is just a view. Herb may be prominent and popular but that doesn't mean you _have_ to do what he does. (He's also responsible for this "almost always auto" abortion.) Of course you are welcome to do so!

Comment: I will drop down to raw pointers _only_ when the performance cost of not doing so is _so high_ as to warrant the loss of clear ownership semantics, and only in a very localised area (so no storage, perhaps a bit of passing into a function - but still, then, const shared_ptr&!)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit If only I had the ability to give more upvotes to your answer and comments here...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Heh; well, I'm not *that much* of a fan. But I liked your answer.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Aww, my nice response was removed. Guess that made the internet a better place somehow.